# The wait operation timed out in Entity Framework in seed Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Asp.Net mvc application with an entity framework. I want run `ALTER DATABASE` in seed method.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
     string.Format(@"Alter Database {0}
        Set FileStream (NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = Full, Directory_Name = '{0}-Directory')",
            builder.InitialCatalog),
            new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString));

command.Connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Connection.Close();
```

My code doesn't work - the wait operation timed out.

**Exception Details:**

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: The most likely cause is that you have the database open (or someone else has it open) in another application (such as SSMS) and the database can't be locked in order to alter it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `DbContext`s `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

```
protected override void Seed(EfContext11 context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("your query");
    base.Seed(context);
}
```